# Is it possible to access to another apps by IONIC?

Tags: ionic-framework, mobile, ionic3

Is it possible for a functional ionic application: grab all applications installed on the phone, before the open that, my application will throw a modal window with a question?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot check for all the apps installed on a phone but you can check for the availability of specific apps using [this native plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-availability/)